# Which should be the list of ignored words for the Naive Bayesian Classifier?

Tags: php, classification, bayesian

I am working with Naive Bayesian classifier over PHP (http://www.xhtml.net/php/PHPNaiveBayesianFilter)

And there's a list of words which can be ignored while training the system. Those words are not saved into the database and therefore not used for the classification.
I would like to improve the system as much as I can so I was wondering if there's any rule or list of typical words to ignore for this kind of systems.

I am currently ignoring words such as "to", "and", "the", "for", "since", "which", "what", "who"... and some typical verbs such as "be", "was", "were", "been"...etc.

Comment: it would depend on what you are training the system for .. bayesian can be used for a lot of this spam filter is just one of them

Comment: Just to classify some text into 4 categories: sports, politics, tech and economy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be dealing with a lot of words .... mostly Adjective and Conjunctions and maybe verbs ....

Its a very long list you need to save as txt or import to your database ..... I suggest you just google and download directly

here are some links

http://www.momswhothink.com/reading/list-of-verbs.html

http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/conjunctions/conjunctions.html

http://www.smart-words.org/transition-words.html

http://www.momswhothink.com/reading/list-of-adjectives.html

The more word you have the better your your system works

Thanks
:)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how much data you have, but if you can use python's package `nltk` you can get a pre-compiled list of "stop" words which are typically removed before running classification. You could also stem/lemmatize (again using `nltk`) all words which often helps for Naive Bayes. Furthermore, `nltk` can identify part of speech reasonably well so you could do more advanced filtering as well (e.g. by keeping nouns, proper nouns, verbs, adverbs and adjectives only)

Comment: I am using PHP. So i dont know if i would be able to use what you are talking about.